# Get ActionResult of another controller-action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, view, controller, httpcontext

I want to store items in the application cache so it's lazy loaded from the main layout view.

I also want to be able to invalidate the cache, so if it's invalid, next time when the items-collection is requested, it's reloaded to that cache location.

Here's what I've implemented:

In the controller:

```
protected IEnumerable<Slide> CachedSlides
{
  get { return HttpContext.Application[SlidesCacheKey] as IEnumerable<Slide>; }
  set { HttpContext.Application[SlidesCacheKey] = value; }
}

private void ClearSlides()
{
  CachedSlides = null;
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public IEnumerable<Slider> GetSlides()
{
  if (CachedSlides == null)
    CachedSlides = Context.Slides.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder).ToArray();
  return CachedSlides;
}
```

I the view (better said in 'a' view, I want to be able to load it from every view):

```
@{
  var sliderController = new LevEl.Controllers.Admin.SliderController().  
  var sliderModel = sliderController.GetSlides();
}
```

It throws an exception because when I initialize the controller in the view, the `HttpContext` property returns null (which leads to a `NullReferenceException`).

Any other ways to implement this will also be welcome.

Comment: Do you want to just call GetSlides() method on every view?

Comment: Yes, unless this is not recommended.

Comment: Do you need the data on different views or do you need the partial view (Html fragments) on different views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you may want to consider using the Cache instead of the Application dictionary, specially since your cached data will expire at some point. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326675/httpruntime-cache-vs-application)

Also, consider if the controller method will just be used by the views because MVC will expose all public methods in the controller. If you don´t want this method to be freely accessed using an URL then set the `[NonAction]` [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385599/asp-net-mvc-nonaction-meaning).

Regarding your error, a quick way to fix it will be accessing the Application object through `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` in the implementation of the CachedSlides property of the controller.

You could also set the ControllerContext when creating a new instance of the SliderController in the view. That way, the HttpContext in the controller will not return null when accessing the CachedSlides property:

```
@{
    var sliderController = new LevEl.Controllers.Admin.SliderController();
    sliderController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(ViewContext.RequestContext, sliderController);
    var sliderModel = sliderController.GetSlides();
}
```

If it makes sense for you to have a base controller class that will handle all of these views, then getting the controller will be cleaner. You would just need to cast the `ViewContext.Controller` instance as that base controller class:

```
var sliderController = ViewContext.Controller as BaseSlideController;
var sliderModel = sliderController.GetSlides();
```

However all of those approaches will require you to add that piece of code to every view. You may consider having a base class for all of your views that will require accessing the Slide collection:

```
public abstract class SlidesEnabledView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<Slide> _slides;
    protected IEnumerable<Slide> Slides
    {
        get
        {
            if(_slides == null)
            {
                var sliderController = ViewContext.Controller as BaseSlideController;
                _slides = sliderController.GetSlides();
            }
            return _slides;
        }
    }
}
```

You will then add the @inherits tag to your views, so they inherit from the base class we have just created (When the @inherits is used, you cannot also use the @model, so in the @inherits you will bound the generic base view type ti a concrete model type). This will allow you to use the property defined in the base `SlidesEnabledView` view class. Assuming the namespace for SlidesEnabledView is Level.ViewClasses.Admin, this would look like:

```
@inherits Level.ViewClasses.Admin.SlidesEnabledView<SomeViewModelClass> 

Number of Slides: @Slides.Count()
```

Finally, if you are using DI through your site and you have configured a DependencyResolver, then you could consider moving the logic for getting the slides into its own class and interface like `ISlidesProvider` and `CachedSlideProvider`. You could then use property injection in the abstract view class for getting an instance of ISlidesProvider that will be used in the Slides property:

```
public interface ISlidesProvider
{ 
    IEnumerable<Slide> GetSlides();
}

public class CachedSlideProvider : ISlidesProvider
{
    //you will need a constructor that takes the "Context" object, which will be injected into this class

    public IEnumerable<Slide> GetSlides()
    {
        if (CachedSlides == null)
            CachedSlides = Context.Slides.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder).ToArray();
        return CachedSlides;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Slide> CachedSlides
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[SlidesCacheKey] as IEnumerable<Slide>; }
        set { System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[SlidesCacheKey] = value; }
    }
}

public abstract class SlidesEnabledView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<Slide> _slides;
    protected IEnumerable<Slide> Slides
    {
        get
        {
            if(_slides == null)
            {
                _slides = this.SlidesProvider.GetSlides();
            }
            return _slides;
        }
    }

    //This property will be set by your DI container
    //You have configured ISlidesProvider to be resolved as CachedSlidesProvider in the DI container
    //You have also implemented and registered an MVC DependencyResolver that uses your DI container
    //For example, using Microsoft Unity you could set this attribute
    [Dependency]
    public ISlidesProvider SlidesProvider { get; set; }        
}
```

As you were creating an instance of the controller using a parameterless constructor, probably you are not using DI on your site. So this DI option may be a bit of overkill just for resolving this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your `GetSlides` method in a `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IEnumerable<Slide> CachedSlides
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Application[SlidesCacheKey] as IEnumerable<Slide>; }
        set { HttpContext.Application[SlidesCacheKey] = value; }
    }

    private void ClearSlides()
    {
        CachedSlides = null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Slide> GetSlides()
    {
        if (CachedSlides == null)
            CachedSlides = Context.Slides.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder).ToArray();
        return CachedSlides;
    }
}
```

So all of your controllers have to inherit from `BaseController`.

In the view you could do this:

```
@{
    var baseController = (BaseController)ViewContext.Controller;
    var slides = baseController.GetSlides();
}
```